# printing float, preserving precision

Tags: c++, c, string, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I am writing a program that prints floating point literals to be used inside another program.

How many digits do I need to print in order to preserve the precision of the original float?

Since a float has `24 * (log(2) / log(10)) = 7.2247199` decimal digits of precision, my initial thought was that printing 8 digits should be enough. But if I'm unlucky, those `0.2247199` get distributed to the left and to the right of the 7 significant digits, so I should probably print 9 decimal digits.

Is my analysis correct? Is 9 decimal digits enough for all cases? Like `printf("%.9g", x);`?

Is there a standard function that converts a float to a string with the minimum number of decimal digits required for that value, in the cases where 7 or 8 are enough, so I don't print unnecessary digits?

Note: I cannot use hexadecimal floating point literals, because standard C++ does not support them.

Comment: Use 1000 digits and clip the trailing zeroes! ;)

Comment: as you cannot convert a binary-based float to decimal fraction without an error, I would propose just dumping the binary representation (or a mantissa + exponent separately).

Comment: @Vlad you can't? Aren't all binary fractions representable as a finite decimal?

Comment: Or, if you want to be guaranteed precise, you can output something like `mantissa / 0b100000`, where the number of zeroes is the exponent. This is not a literal, but at least a constant expression which will anyway be calculated at compile-time.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes That would generate too much noise. For example, `printf("%.1000g\n", 3.14159265f);` prints `3.1415927410125732421875`.

Comment: @Vlad How will dumping the binary representation give me a floating point literal?

Comment: @Fred: it won't, but at least this representation is exact, so you can pick it up in the other program an make exactly the same float value from it.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Can you clarify the aim here?  Is it to get an exact decimal representation of the float?  (If so, R.Martinho is on the right track.)  Or is it to print to sufficient precision that it can be unambiguously parsed back to the original float value?

Comment: If the aim is to use the floating point literal across programs, then I guess @Vlad 's suggestion is the most fool-proof and saves you a lot of headache. Its upto to the other program which reads the float output of your program to do whatever it wants to do.

Comment: Is just for printing? Did you know about [`setprecision`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/)?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The latter: "to print to sufficient precision that it can be unambiguously parsed back to the original float value".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to guarantee that a binary->decimal->binary roundtrip recovers the original binary value, [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Character_representation) requires

```
The original binary value will be preserved by converting to decimal and back again using:[10]

    5 decimal digits for binary16
    9 decimal digits for binary32
    17 decimal digits for binary64
    36 decimal digits for binary128

For other binary formats the required number of decimal digits is

    1 + ceiling(p*log10(2)) 

where p is the number of significant bits in the binary format, e.g. 24 bits for binary32.
```

In C, the functions you can use for these conversions are snprintf() and strtof/strtod/strtold().

Of course, in some cases even more digits can be useful (no, they are not always "noise", depending on the implementation of the decimal conversion routines such as snprintf() ). Consider e.g. [printing dyadic fractions](http://www.exploringbinary.com/print-precision-of-dyadic-fractions-varies-by-language/).

Comment: +1 For the standard-proofed answer (though assuming an IEEE compliant implementation, but who doesn't use IEEE floats anyway).

Comment: @ChristianRau: Everybody more or less uses IEEE floats these days yes. However, the caveat is whether your decimal conversion functions are correctly rounded for all inputs, which is perhaps less certain. But if you need a decimal representation, not much you can do about it (except implementing your own bug-free decimal conversions, good luck!).

Comment: @ChristianRau, janneb: It's not universal.  I still occasionally have to deal with seismic data that's been generated in IBM floating-point format!

Comment: They are noise in the sense that they don't provide any additional precision; that is, `3.1415927f` and `3.1415927410125732421875f` denote the exact same `float` value. The digits after the `927` are completely determined by the digits before; they don't provide any new information. So why print them, if the intent is to produce the shortest `float` literal possible?

Comment: @FredOverflow: The point about noise wasn't intended as an answer to your question directly, but moreof a general point that sometimes more digits than is required for a binary->decimal->binary roundtrip can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

> 24 * (log(2) / log(10)) = 7.2247199

That's pretty representative for the problem.  It makes no sense whatsoever to express the number of significant digits with an accuracy of 0.0000001 digits.  You are converting numbers to text for the benefit of a *human*, not a machine.  A human couldn't care less, and would much prefer, if you wrote

> 24 * (log(2) / log(10)) = 7

Trying to display 8 significant digits just generates random noise digits.  With non-zero odds that 7 is already too much because floating point error accumulates in calculations.  Above all, print numbers using a reasonable unit of measure.  People are interested in millimeters, grams, pounds, inches, etcetera.  No architect will care about the size of a window expressed more accurately than 1 mm.  No window manufacturing plant will *promise* a window sized as accurate as that.

Last but not least, you cannot ignore the accuracy of the numbers you feed into your program.  Measuring the speed of an unladen European swallow down to 7 digits is not possible.  It is roughly 11 meters per second, 2 digits at best.  So performing calculations on that speed and printing a result that has *more* significant digits produces nonsensical results that promise accuracy that isn't there.

Comment: *to be used inside another program* => it seems that your assumption about a human reading the output is erroneous.

Comment: Hmm, that did indeed not register.  Strange thing to do.  Well, easy fix, as long as a human never sees it then print digits galore.

Comment: I hate it when it looks like my brain edited out the one import word in the text :x It also looks like Fred was concerned about space consumption (and I guess performance).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a C library that is conforming to C99 (and if your float types have a base that is a power of 2 :) the `printf` format character `%a` can print floating point values without lack of precision in hexadecimal form, and utilities as `scanf` and `strod` will be able to read them.

Answer (score 2):

If the program is meant to be read by a computer, I would do the simple trick of using `char*` aliasing.

- alias `float*` to `char*`
- copy into an `unsigned` (or whatever unsigned type is sufficiently large) via `char*` aliasing
- print the `unsigned` value

Decoding is just reversing the process (and on most platform a direct `reinterpret_cast` can be used).

Comment: And in which way does this give a float literal? Of course you can always use the binary representation to get exact precision with few space, but well...

Comment: @ChristianRau: my idea was to challenge the initial requirement that for two programs to exchange floating point numbers a literal representation would be required. Since the format is normalized (and mandated by the Standard), using the binary representation is portable (at the potential endianness issue).

Comment: @dbaupp: in practice yes (thus the `reinterpret_cast` bit). In theory, aliasing to other types than `char*` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @MatthieuM. So it was just a *"do it differently"* comment, diguised as an answer?

Comment: @ChristianRau: YMMV. Most of SO questions suffer of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The original issue is to exchange floating point literals between two programs and the OP seems to assume that human-readable format is required, but does not offer any reason other, maybe, than its references to the Standard, requiring well-defined behavior. So I proposed a solution that works within the reasons specified to accomplish the goal of exchanging data, but otherwise ignores the self-restrictions the OP seems to have imposed himself.

Answer (score 1):

The floating-point-to-decimal conversion used in Java is guaranteed to be produce the least number of decimal digits beyond the decimal point needed to distinguish the number from its neighbors (more or less).

You can copy the algorithm from here: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java.html
Pay attention to the `FloatingDecimal(float)` constructor and the `toJavaFormatString()` method.

Comment: Exactly where in that 2800+ lines of code does the algorithm start?

Comment: @Gabe It starts in the constructor and ends in the method I indicate. The full string is returned by the expression `new FloatingDecimal(number).toJavaFormatString()`.

Comment: @sehe I'm not saying you should copy the *code*, just the algorithm.

Comment: Neither of those functions contain any obvious means to determine the number of decimal digits needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you read these papers (see below), you'll find that there are some algorithm that print the minimum number of decimal digits such that the number can be re-interpreted unchanged (i.e. by scanf).

Since there might be several such numbers, the algorithm also pick the nearest decimal fraction to the original binary fraction (I named float value).

A pity that there's no such standard library in C.

- http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~burger/FP-Printing-PLDI96.pdf
- http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/email/pdfq3pavhBfih.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sprintf`. I am not sure whether this answers your question exactly though, but anyways, here is the sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( void )
{
float d_n = 123.45;
char s_cp[13] = { '\0' };
char s_cnp[4] = { '\0' };
/*
* with sprintf you need to make sure there's enough space
* declared in the array
*/
sprintf( s_cp, "%.2f", d_n );
printf( "%s\n", s_cp );
/*
* snprinft allows to control how much is read into array.
* it might have portable issues if you are not using C99
*/
snprintf( s_cnp, sizeof s_cnp - 1 , "%f", d_n );
printf( "%s\n", s_cnp );
getchar();
return 0;
}
/* output :
* 123.45
* 123
*/
```

Comment: This is a sensible approach, but one thing we've found with using sprintf is that the rounding can be different for different platforms.

Answer (score -1):

With something like

```
def f(a):
    b=0
    while a != int(a): a*=2; b+=1
    return a, b
```

(which is Python) you should be able to get mantissa and exponent in a loss-free way.

In C, this would probably be

```
struct float_decomp {
    float mantissa;
    int exponent;
}

struct float_decomp decomp(float x)
{
    struct float_decomp ret = { .mantissa = x, .exponent = 0};
    while x != floor(x) {
        ret.mantissa *= 2;
        ret.exponent += 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

But be aware that still not all values can be represented in that way, it is just a quick shot which should give the idea, but probably needs improvement.

Comment: It is very helpful to -1 without any comment.