# Does insertion and extraction of a floating point number to some of the standard stream classes preserves its value?

Tags: c++, floating-point

When I debug I sometimes want to print the floating point number returned by a function and use it as an input value for another function. I wonder what are the *default* parameters which guide the formatting of the floating point numbers.

Are f1 and f2 always the same in the following code?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  std::stringstream ss;

  float f1 = .1f;
  ss << f1;

  float f2;
  ss >> f2;

  assert(f1 == f2);
  return 0;
}
```

Can I write a bunch of floating point numbers to std::cout or std::ofsteam and read them back to get exactly the same numbers or should I explicitly set the amount of numbers after the decimal mark (like it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10896466/18775)?

What bothers me is that although .1 is not representable as a binary fraction it is still formatted correctly by the standard streams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessarily.  By default, `ostream` outputs 6 digits of
precision.  To be able to "round trip" a float, you need
a precision of `std::numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10` (which
is 9 for the most common representation).  If the stream is
being used for persistance, and you're only persisting floats,
just set the precision before writing anything, e.g.:

```
ss.precision( std::numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10 );
```

(If you need to handle both `float` and `double`, and don't want
the extra digits on `float`, you'll need to set the precision
each time you output a floating point value.)

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about max_digits10.  Thanks, James.

Comment: Could you tell me where exactly I can find the "6 digits of precision"? Is it implementation defined or standard?

Comment: @mezhaka In table 128 of the standard.  The state after initialization is
defined, with `flags() == skipws | dec`. `precision() == 6` and
`fill() == widen( ' ' )`.

Comment: To clarify: James Kanze reffers to 2011 standard. It is in table 89 (basic_ios::init() effects) of the 2003 standard (search for "ISO/IEC 14882:2003(E)").

Comment: @mezhaka Yes.  I should have specified that the table number I gave was from C++11.

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not guaranteed to be the same.

What's happening is that the float itself has more precision than it'll print out as by default, so as long as what you read in has fewer significant digits than the default output precision, what you print out will (at least usually) be rounded back to the value you read in.

If, however, you have data that uses the full precision of your `float`, and you read it in and then write it back out at full precision, you'll start to see differences.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::istringstream buffer("0.1");
    float value;
    buffer >> value;
    std::cout << value << "\n"; 
    std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << value;
}
```

Result:

```
0.1
0.1000000015
```

In this case, the trailing `15` is (approximately) the difference between 0.1 and the closest approximation to it that my compiler's float can represent.

Answer (score -1):

Even more important, assert(f1 == f2); when f1 and f2 are both floating point numbers is rarely correct.  You want something like assert(abs(f1 - f2) < tolerance);  There are several techniques commonly used for choosing tolerance.  Which one you should use depends on the problem your program is addressing.

Comment: I don't think that applies to this situation, in which the OP needs exact reproduction of the original floating point value. Only an `==` test can tell whether the procedure met that requirement.